# Android: How to get the database row id from onItemClickListener when using Custom Adapter?

Tags: android, sqlite, custom-adapter, rowid

I am trying to obtain the database row id from the listview item in onItemClickListener when using a custom adapter.

I have tried getting the id from the "long id" inside of the onItemClickListener but it seems to return just the row id of the item in the actual list, not the database row id.

Here is my onItemClickListener:

```
 mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

            String selected = (String) 
mListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            mTextView = findViewById(R.id.Words);
            mNumberTextView = findViewById(R.id.Number);
            mId = id;
            mAdapterView = adapterView;
            mPositionForRow = position;

            mCopied = 
mHeaderNameTextView.getText().toString();
            mNumberCopied = Integer.toString(mSelected + 1);
            mNumberCopied = 
mNumberTextView.getText().toString();
            mPosition = position + 1;
            mCopiedListItem = mBookCopied + " " + 
mNumberCopied + ":" + mPosition + "\n\n" + selected;

            showMenu(view);
        }
    });
```

Here is my custom adapter:

```
public Adapter(Context context, int resource1, List<String> lines) {
    super(context, resource1, lines);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mResource1 = resource1;
    this.mLines = lines;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull 
ViewGroup parent) {

    View listItem = convertView;
    int pos = position + 1;

    if (listItem == null) {
        listItem = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(mResource1, 
parent, false);
    }
    mNumberTextView = (TextView) 
listItem.findViewById(R.id.Number);
    mNumberTextView.setText(String.valueOf(pos) + " ");

    mTextView = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.Words);
    mTextView.setText(mLines.get(position));


    }

    return listItem;
}
}
```

When a list item is clicked on, a menu pops up. If the user selects "select item", it should get the actual database row id from the item click but it returns the list item number which is not what I need. I also convert the long to an int in the process. I just didn't see a need to include that method.

Here is that menu option:

```
case R.id.select_item:
                    Log.d("TAG", "mId =" + mId);

                mRowPositionInt = (safeLongToInt(mId));
                updateData(1, mRowPositionInt);
                Log.d("TAG", "mRowPosition =" + mRowPositionInt);
                mSharedPreferences.edit().putInt("RowPositionSqlite", 
mRowPositionInt).apply();
                Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
"Select Item Button Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast2.show();

            }
```

There are no error messages it just does not return the actual database row id. Any advice would be helpful. I have been through other posts but not applied to my situation. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The `long id` you get back is the long you return from your adapter's [`getItemId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemId(int)).

If you want a database row id to be return rather than just the position, you need to:

1. Pass in the database row ids to your adapter
2. Have `getItemId()` return the correct id for the given position.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to do this and let you know. I appreciate the response.

Comment: Ian, for clarification can you help me to understand it? I still need the position passed in through the getView method. How do I also pass the database row ids through and use the getItemId() method to get it? Can you give me an example with the code I provided? I appreciate your help.

Comment: You have full control over the constructor of your `Adapter` class, just pass in another `List<Long>` for your list of database ids and use that to implement your `getItemId()`. Nothing you do with `getItemId()` affects the `position` that is passed to your methods (that's why it is called `position`, not `id`)

Comment: Thank you. I will try it and let you know.